# Need to display month as January, February, etc..rather than a number

Tags: mysql

below is the MySQL code, it works but i need to display the month as January, Febuary, etc...

```
select FirstName, LastName, extract(month from BirthDate) as BirthMonth
from employees;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup the documentation for MySQL's DATE_FORMAT() Function.

It offers a wide variety to format date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`MONTHNAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) function:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, MONTHNAME(BirthDate) as BirthMonth
FROM   employees;
```